# typoscript find out if page to select from is hidden

Tags: select, typo3, typoscript

I'm running a select from a static page (id 155 in my case). I only want this select to perform if the page itself is not hidden in the Backend. Is there a way to achieve this? I thought about using an sql clause in the "where" part but as far as i understand these clauses only affect content elements on the page but not the page (pidInList) itself...

```
   15 = CONTENT
   15 {
   wrap = <div id="xyz">|</div>
   table = tt_content
   select {
      pidInList = 155
      orderBy = sorting
      where = colPos=0
   }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What version of TYPO3 are you running? What type (standard, sysfolder, etc.) is the page 155? I'm asking because I've started to doubt my own answer. I think `CONTENT` should not return any result when the page itself is hidden.

Comment: Isn't it that you just want to avoid the `wrap` when the page is hidden and no content is retrieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to avoid the wrap when the page is hidden and no content is to be displayed, use the `required` attribute:

```
15 = CONTENT
15 {
  stdWrap {
    required = 1
    wrap = <div id="xyz">|</div>
  }
  table = tt_content
  select {
    pidInList = 155
    orderBy = sorting
    where = colPos=0
  }
}
```

Comment: this works perfectly fine on TYPO3 4.5.30. Actually I knew about the stdWrap.required and have used it quite a bit but thought it would fire anyway since the select selects the contents of the page disregarding if its hidden or not. and since there are a couple of non-hidden contents in the page at all time i thought it would always return 1. in my opinion this is actually not the way it should work but rather the subquery should be necessary ant the required just apply to the wrap. but since it does work and it's what i need in this case i won't complain :) ... thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Use subquery

```
where = colPos=0 AND (SELECT hidden FROM pages WHERE uid=tt_content.pid)=0
```

(it's fixed version of previous answer)

Note: **[cascaval's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20268830/1066240)** usage of stdWrap will allow you additionaly to hide the wrapping div if there's no records available, so with combination of all answers you have ready to use solution ;)

Comment: I like the subquery! Though I really wonder if that's his problem because in my tests I haven't managed to retrieve the content when the page itself is hidden.

Comment: @cascaval acctually I found exactly the same (now, when was checking the case), if page is hidden it doesn't fetch records anyway. So finnaly OP can use it to check if page is hidden in menu `AND (SELECT nav_hide FROM pages...` ;)

Comment: in my understanding of .required the subquery should be necessary and cascavals reply only work or the wrap itself but it does work in 4.5.30 without the subquery so i chose his way. thanks!

Comment: I don't know what is your understanding of the `required` property but it simply (and only) stops further processing in the `stdWrap` if the current content is empty (which it is as the select doesn't return anything). As the `stdWrap` properties are applied in certain order and `wrap` comes after `required`, `wrap` is never applied.